# Java Path Finder for Bytecode Verification in an existing project, Bytecode Verification

Tags: java, bytecode

I'm trying to use JPF to verify my bytecode generated while runtime with javassist.

The code I'm trying to verify is supplied by the user while my program is running. As I can't check all OOP models and stuff like that I need a verification process before running his code.

At the moment I simply generate bytecode with javassist from his classes.

My problem now is that I get exceptions sometimes because the user did some inheritance mistakes and stuff and my application shuts down with an exception cause I tried to load and execute his classes.

Therefore I would like to verify that generated bytecode in runtime to avoid such exceptions and to know earlier if the classes supplied from the user are faulty (or contain any problem).

Is this possible with JPF while in runtime?

Any other solutions on this?

Thanks!

Comment: try to do a hash on the byte code; perhaps select bytes at different/random locations and see if they match; it should be much faster than checking the whole file

Comment: A hash would be just to compare to things or am I wrong? I need to check wether if the code is valid and can be run without getting an exception or not!

Comment: My impression was that you were doing equality on all bytes ... not that the bytes are valid code. Did I missinterpret?

Comment: Yes i think you missinterpreted it. I'm trying to verificate if the bytecode, generated from the classes I created after compilation, is valid or not.

Comment: May you post a SSCCE code http://sscce.org/ we may play with (error injection...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many points to check:

- the bytecode itself according to the [class file format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10)
- the runtime phases: [loading, linking and initializing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html)

From my point of view, a `ClassLoader` does all that steps but it generally loads one Class at a time, and only on demand.

In your context, I propose you write a `ClassLoader` that loads in sequence all classes from generated bytecodes and reports each failing class name with caught exceptions. The ClassLoader is instantiated with the reference to the relevant parent ClassLoader and is discarded after the test passed, the generated bytecode is then loaded by the original ClassLoader of your runtime context.

Probably this class loading check may be implemented thanks to OSGi but it will require more efforts than a standalone ClassLoader.

Answer (score 2):

As JPF uses BCEL [Stand-alone Bytecode Verifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340498/stand-alone-bytecode-verifier) might be helpful. Just programmatically invoke the Verifier class - or even dive into the details of this class.
hth

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure but some tests showed to me what I meant to read: "Especially, we will not deal with the security constraints that the Java Virtual Machine has to check at run-time, i.e. the byte code verifier." So it looks for me as the bytecode verifier used by BCEL (or Javassist) is no a 100% clean check, that's why I'm trying to use JPF

Comment: My mistake. I stumpled upon an old version of JPF that depended on BCEL, but I just saw that new versions are not. So forget my comment...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an absolute requirement to use JPF, the ASM library includes CheckClassAdapter which can verify byte code. It is only a sanity check however - I don't believe it will catch problems with inheritance etc.

Comment: That's the problem, as I said I need 100% correct verification which checked oop models and which is secure to run on the jvm without exceptions. In addition to that, I need to get correct and good error messages from the verifier which ASM does not provide